# Accessing AWS resources (aws xray) from GCP or Azure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda, aws-xray

We would like to access the aws xray which is deployed in multiple regions like Europe, US-east and US-west.
I would like to access these using access key id and secret access key id and maybe session token as well.
I want to know is it necessary to specify the region while accessing the aws xray resources of these regions.
What if I don't specify the region and just specify the keys to access the AWS resource (aws xray); will we be able to access those?

Customer-centric exact issue:

We have to talk to a customer, he is going to say that he has deployed AWS xray in three regions.
We usually access the Customer's resource and get data and do some processing.
So What details we should say to the customer that we would need from him ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a role that users in other accounts or people outside of your organization can use to access your resources. You can specify who is trusted to assume the role. For services that support resource-based policies or access control lists (ACLs), you can use those policies to grant people access to your resources.

In case you need to provide access to an externally authenticated users (identity federation): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_common-scenarios_federated-users.html

Comment: How would I make request to access the AWS resource on the client's side? using rest or http request. that would require access key id and secret key id of AWS resource. I want to know is it necessary to specify the region of the client resource also or without that I'll be able to access ?

Comment: If X-Ray is a regional service then you would need to set the region on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

AWS X-Ray traces are stored in specific regions as configured on X-Ray Daemon or the AWS managed services. If you want to use X-Ray APIs to send or fetch traces, you'll have to provide the region as well.

Are there any specific X-Ray APIs/Resources you're looking to use?